# Paperclip urls missing id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I've been uploading images fine using [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) and [rails-tinymce-imageupload](https://github.com/PerfectlyNormal/tinymce-rails-imageupload) up until now:

```
<img src="/system/posts/files/000/000/277/original/example.jpeg">
```

I must have inadvertently changed something because now when I upload an image it skips the id like so:

```
 <img src="/system/posts/files//original/example.jpeg">
```

Any ideas what messed this up? Sorry for the lack of details but I'm unsure of what else to add.

Comment: check your model for any changes to the :url parameter under `has_attached_file`

Comment: All I've ever had in the model is 'has_attached_file :file'. Is the :url parameter necessary?

Comment: Found the problem :) I had added validates :body, presence: true in the model which conflicts with the image uploading. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to remove this line from the model:

```
validates :body, presence: true
```